# Change fonts in notepad application

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt

A friend and myself are making a NotePad. We are trying to get fonts to change when you click the appropriate button. For example if I press the Italic Button the text I write after that will be Italic until I press the Normal button which will turn it back to the normal font. As far as I can tell the code looks pretty good but when I press the font buttons nothing happens. Here is ALL the code.

```
package com.note.pad;

import javax.swing.*; // for the main JFrame design
import java.awt.*; // for the GUI stuff
import java.awt.event.*; // for the event handling
import java.util.Scanner; // for reading from a file
import java.io.*; // for writing to a file

public class Notepad  extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private TextArea textArea = new TextArea("", 0,0,TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
    private MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar(); //First, create a menu bar.
    private Menu file = new Menu(); //File menu.
    private Menu fonts = new Menu(); //Font menu.
    private MenuItem italicFont = new MenuItem();
    private MenuItem normalFont = new MenuItem();
    private MenuItem openFile = new MenuItem(); //Open option
    private MenuItem saveFile = new MenuItem(); //Save option
    private MenuItem close = new MenuItem(); //Close option

    public Notepad(){
        this.setSize(500, 300); //Size of Notepad
        this.setTitle("BenPad"); //Name of Notepad
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Closes when you hit X button
        this.textArea.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic", Font.BOLD, 12)); //Font
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(textArea);
        this.setMenuBar(this.menuBar);
        this.menuBar.add(this.file);
        this.menuBar.add(this.fonts);
        this.file.setLabel("File");
        this.fonts.setLabel("Fonts");
        this.italicFont.setLabel("Italic");
        this.normalFont.setLabel("Normal");
        this.fonts.add(this.italicFont);
        this.openFile.setLabel("Open");
        this.fonts.add(this.normalFont);
        this.openFile.addActionListener(this);
        this.openFile.setShortcut(new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_0, false));
        this.file.add(this.openFile);
        this.saveFile.setLabel("Save");
        this.saveFile.addActionListener(this);
        this.saveFile.setShortcut(new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_S, false));
        this.file.add(this.saveFile);
        this.close.setLabel("Close");
        this.close.setShortcut(new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_F4, false));
        this.close.addActionListener(this);
        this.file.add(this.close);


    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == this.close)
                this.dispose(); 


            else if (e.getSource() == this.openFile) {
                JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser(); 
                int option = open.showOpenDialog(this); 

                if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    this.textArea.setText(""); 
                    try {

                        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(open.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                        while (scan.hasNext()) 
                            this.textArea.append(scan.nextLine() + "\n"); 
                                } catch (Exception ex) { 

                                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                                }   
                            }
                        }


            else if (e.getSource() == this.italicFont) {
                    this.textArea.setFont(new Font("Italic", Font.ITALIC, 12));
            }


            else if (e.getSource() == this.normalFont) {
                this.textArea.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic", Font.BOLD, 12));
            }


                        else if (e.getSource() == this.saveFile) {
                            JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser(); 
                            int option = save.showSaveDialog(this); 

                            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                                try {

                                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(save.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                                    out.write(this.textArea.getText()); 
                                    out.close(); 
                                } catch (Exception ex) { 
                                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Notepad app = new Notepad();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't mix Swing components with AWT components!  Also note that 1) There is no AWT component that supports styled text.  2) A `JTextArea` won't support styled text, but either of a `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane` will.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Notepad extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private TextArea textArea = new TextArea("");//, 0,0,TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
    private MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar(); //First, create a menu bar.
    private Menu file = new Menu(); //File menu.
    private Menu fonts = new Menu(); //Font menu.
    private MenuItem italicFont = new MenuItem();
    private MenuItem normalFont = new MenuItem();
    private MenuItem openFile = new MenuItem(); //Open option
    private MenuItem saveFile = new MenuItem(); //Save option
    private MenuItem close = new MenuItem(); //Close option

    public Notepad(){
        setSize(500, 300); //Size of Notepad
        setTitle("BenPad"); //Name of Notepad
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Closes when you hit X button
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic", Font.BOLD, 12)); //Font
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(textArea);
        setMenuBar(this.menuBar);
        menuBar.add(this.file);
        menuBar.add(this.fonts);
        file.setLabel("File");
        fonts.setLabel("Fonts");
        italicFont.setLabel("Italic");
        normalFont.setLabel("Normal");
        fonts.add(this.italicFont);
        openFile.setLabel("Open");
        fonts.add(this.normalFont);
        italicFont.addActionListener(this);
        normalFont.addActionListener(this);
        openFile.addActionListener(this);
        openFile.setShortcut(new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_0, false));
        file.add(this.openFile);
        saveFile.setLabel("Save");
        saveFile.addActionListener(this);
        saveFile.setShortcut(new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_S, false));
        file.add(this.saveFile);
        close.setLabel("Close");
        close.setShortcut(new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_F4, false));
        close.addActionListener(this);
        file.add(this.close);


    }
@Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == this.close)
                this.dispose(); 


            else if (e.getSource() == this.openFile) {
                JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser(); 
                int option = open.showOpenDialog(this); 

                if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    this.textArea.setText(""); 
                    try {

                        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(open.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                        while (scan.hasNext()) 
                            this.textArea.append(scan.nextLine() + "\n"); 
                                } catch (Exception ex) { 

                                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                                }   
                            }
                        }


            else if (e.getSource() == this.italicFont) {
                    this.textArea.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 12));

            }


            else if (e.getSource() == this.normalFont) {
                this.textArea.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic", Font.BOLD, 12));
            }


                        else if (e.getSource() == this.saveFile) {
                            JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser(); 
                            int option = save.showSaveDialog(this); 

                            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                                try {

                                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(save.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                                    out.write(this.textArea.getText()); 
                                    out.close(); 
                                } catch (Exception ex) { 
                                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Notepad app = new Notepad();
        //app.setVisible(true);
    }

}

If you want text you insert before you press italic font menu then you have to use JEditorPane/JTextPane
```